# Array whose each clip is linked to its equal clip of another array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, for-loop, addchild

Hello I apologize in advance for my question which I'm sure is pretty basic.

On a map are set 33 landmarks with an array calling a class in the library. 
A second array defines the coordinates of those landmarks.

```
for  (var i:uint = 0; i < 33; i++) { 
     mark[i] = new landMark();
     landMarks.addChild(mark[i]);
     mark[i].x = lmxy[i]['x'];
     mark[i].y = lmxy[i]['y'];
}


var lmxy:Array = [{x:1620,y:880},{x:1850, y:1050},etc...];
```

So far so good, the landmarks show each in its right place.

The third array contains different legends  supposed to show when a landmark is clicked.
So the landmark [1] should show the legend [1] and the landmark [31] the legend [31]

```
var lgd:Array = [lgdA, lgdB, etc... ];

var legends:MovieClip;
for (var j:uint=0;j<lgd.length;j++) {
    legends = new lgd[j](); 
    legends.x = 300;legends.y = 170;
```

}

Edit cause obviously that was unclear : 
I tried that in the loop to link the marks to the legends but I get an error :

```
    mark[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getLgd);
    function getLgd(e:Event):void {stage.addChild (lgd[i]);}
```

Any help would be very welcome !

Comment: You should add only the `legend` of the clicked `mark`, not all legends in the same time ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `i` doesn't have a definition. The only way for you to find out which of the landmarks were clicked is to find its index in the array, then you can add the legend that has the same index. Because the index isn't passed from the event listener, you need to use `e` which has the `target` property.

This should do the trick:

```
mark[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getLgd);

function getLgd(e:Event):void
{
    var i:int = mark.indexOf(e.target);
    stage.addChild(lgd[i]);
}
```